How to configure Japanese Input in 24.04 or CJK or non-Latin input in general?
I may be wrong, but it looks like ibus-anthy was dropped from Ubuntu 24.04 LTS (noble).
This is surprising when you look over to Red Hat where ibus-anthy is also listed as the reference for Japanese input. There is ibus-mozc, but according to InputMethodBuster on the Debian Wiki is "limited to popular platforms".
Am I just too early and Package Maintainers / MOTU's will take care of a Fail To Build From Source issue (FTBFS)?
On second thought -- My actual question: Is there some kind of package group or meta package like @input-methods like on Red Hat that just pulls in the recommended packages for a release and lets us stop worrying about over-specific package names being available?
So far I have found task-japanese-gnome-desktop, but it looks like no one has ever mentioned it here on AskUbuntu. Wishful thinking that there must be some consistency brings me to task-korean-gnome-desktop vs. task-korean-desktop. Which makes me just want to pick ibus-mozc and ibus-hangul instead.

I'm running into the same thing. It doesn't seem that there's any documentation on to what to use in place of ibus-anthy for Japanese input.

I realize it's been 2 months, but given this is still one of the top results for Ubuntu 24.04 and Japanese, here goes...
Editor's Note: I misread the original question as Kubuntu, not Ubuntu (I'm a Kubuntu user). Oops. I think I have Ubuntu as well correct, so instructions for that first, then longer Kubuntu instructions afterwards (for anyone who comes across this thread in the future).
Ubuntu:

sudo apt install ibus ibus-mozc
Settings > Keyboard > Add Input Source > ... > Search "mozc" > Other > Japanese (Mozc)
Changing input method is in the top right.

Kubuntu:
I used ibus-mozc in 23.10 and before. I ended up reinstalling Kubuntu while upgrading to 24.04, but I don't remember how I set it up last time and/or something changed.
I like mozc a bit more, but for the rest of this replace mozc with anthy if that's your jam. From a quick check, anthy looks like it works.

For Kubuntu, I ended up using fcitx5 instead (I think it's installed by default?). sudo apt install fcitx5 fcitx5-mozc


Open System Settings -> Regional Settings -> Input Method (if fcitx5 is running, you should see a penguin icon) -> Add Input Method
Search for "Mozc" (don't select the plain Japanese ones) and add it.
Hit "Apply".

Clicking (or right-clicking) the keyboard icon in the taskbar should work!
One more thing -
It looks like ibus and fcitx5 don't play nice together. Zoom (the video calling app) "depends" on ibus. Solutions include repackaging it or using a dummy package. I ended up going with the latter.
Hopefully this was helpful to someone.
